# Use canActivate to determine showing a link

Tags: angular

I want to use my AuthGuard implementing CanActivate to determine whether i should show a link or not. However i can't seem to get the Route to check canActivate

I've tried creating the below function

Ts file:

```
  shouldShowLink(route: Route) {
    const activate = route.canActivate;
    return activate;
  }
```

Template:

```html
<li *ngIf="shouldShowLink(['account/overview'])" class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['account/overview']" routerLinkActive="active">Brugere</a>
</li>
```

Routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {

   path: 'account', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], data: {roles: ['Administrator']},
   children: [
     {
       path: 'create', component: CreateUserComponent,
     },
     {
       path: 'overview', component: UseroverviewComponent
     },
     {
       path: 'userinfo/:id', component: UserInfoComponent
     }
  ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AccountRoutingModule { }
```

AuthGuard:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private authorizationService: AuthorizationService) { }


  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (!this.authorizationService.UserLoggedIn) {
      return false;
    }

    if (this.authorizationService.UserRole === 'EQAdministrator') {
      return true;
    }

    if (route.data.roles && route.data.roles.indexOf(this.authorizationService.UserRole) === -1) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

The route property gives an array where the first and only entry are the route i passed it. if i remove the array, i just get a string with the route, not the actual route.

I made a [StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vfzh4c)

Comment: - `['account/overview']` isn't a route, it's an array of strings. 
- You test `canActivate` on the supposed route, but it's an array of strings. 
- You also return `route.canActivate`, which is a function and is defined, meaning it is truthy, and will alwats return true. 

That's not how it works. `*ngIf` expects a boolean, and `canActivate` returns a boolean. You have to call your function to make it work. 

If you want help, please provide a [mcve] of your issue, with your actual code, because right now, we just can't help you (just tell you what's wrong).

Comment: I think what i wan't just isn't possible. It just seems like it would be possible to determine whether or not the user can see the link, based on the routes data, instead of having the same data, what roles can activate/see the route, in multiple places.

Comment: that's definitely possible, you're just doing it wrong.

Comment: I've updated the post with my Routing and AuthGuard. That should create a minimal reproducible example i believe

Comment: that's you that are supposed to produce a [mcve]. Go to https://stackblitz.com and make it so that it shows your current issue.

Comment: Updated the question with StackBlitz

Answer (score 1):

This does not currently seem possible.  Please upvote the related [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44556)